# How to get configurable attribute label and value in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, collection, custom

To use Object Manager is not a proper way but this code is for testing purpose only.

I want to get attribute value which is available in configurable products. I have tried with below code, but I get an all Attribute value which is assigned in the attributes drop-down list.

**Please See below code**

```
   <?php
    $objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $product    = $repository->getById($p_coll->getId());    
    $data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($product);
    $options = array();

    foreach ($data as $attr) {
        foreach ($attr as $p) {
            $options[] = $p['attribute_code'];
        }
    }


    $statu = 0;


    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    foreach (array_unique($options) as $code) {
        $attribute     = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $code);
        $options       = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $optionsExists = array();
        if ($options) {
            echo $code;
            echo "<select>";
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                    //$optionsExists[] = $option['label']; 
                if ($option['label']) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $option['label'] . "'>" . $option['label'] . "</option>";
                }
            }
            echo "</select>";
        }


    }
    ?>
```

**Please see below screen shot**

[image]

There are only 2 colours available for this configurable product, but all colour options show in my collection. Please see below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please try below code and please enter product id to get the value**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
// adding bootstrap
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(**product id**);

$productTypeInstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
$productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $key => $value) {

    $tmp_option = $value['values'];
    if(count($tmp_option) > 0)
    {
        echo "<h3>".$value['label']."</h3>";
        echo "<select id='".$key."_".$value['label']."'>";
        foreach ($tmp_option as $tmp) 
        {
            echo "<option value='".$key."_".$tmp['value_index']."'>".$tmp['label']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get selected attribute value ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function execute()
{
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
     ->addFieldToFilter(
        'frontend_input',
        'select'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'is_user_defined',
        1
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'is_global',
        1
    );

    foreach($collection as $attributes)
    {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        echo $attributeId."<br/>";
        $attribute =$this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeId );//"color" is the attribute_code
        $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
            foreach ( $allOptions as $instance ) {
                $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
                echo $id ;
                $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
                echo $value;
            }
        }
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
```

This will give all configurable product attribute .place this code wherever you want!!!!!
This will give you attribute id and all its value

Answer (score 0):

```
$shouldSave = false;
foreach ($productSkuList as $productSku) {
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($productSku);
    $product->load($productId);
    if (empty($productId)) {
        continue;
    } elseif (!$shouldSave) {
        $shouldSave = true;
    }
    $buyRequest = ['product' => $productId, 'qty' => 1];
    if (!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        $parentIds = $this->productIndexer->getRelationsByChild($productId);
        if ($parentIds) {
            $buyRequest['product'] = $parentIds[0];
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $parentProduct */
            $parentProduct = $this->productFactory->create();
            $parentProduct->load($buyRequest['product']);
            $configurableCode = \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE;
            if ($parentProduct->getTypeId() == $configurableCode) {
                /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $productType */
                $productType = $parentProduct->getTypeInstance();
                $buyRequest['super_attribute'] = [];
                foreach ($productType->getConfigurableAttributes($parentProduct) as $attribute) {
                    $attributeCode = $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
                    $buyRequest['super_attribute'][$attribute->getAttributeId()] = $product
                        ->getData($attributeCode);
                }
                $product = $parentProduct;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```