# How to get configurable attributes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product

I know how to get the attributes from the configurable product. I need to know how to get the configurable attributes options label and values **without using the product Id** so that i can create a configurable product programmatically myself using those attributes.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232449/how-to-get-configurable-attribute-label-and-value-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

follow this link and it is a work for me:-
https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-super-attribute-from-configurable-products-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: I need the attribute options without using the already existing configurable product.